# VB Hiding Child Forms

Tags: forms, mdi

I'm making a program that involves children, kind of.  I'm using `form2.Owner = me` instead of parenting Mdi.

I have a button on `Form1` that needs to hide the child forms, or even move them to back so I can only see `Form1`.  Is there anyway to do this?  If so, I hope there's also a way to undo as well?

If you only know of a way for parenting Mdi, I'll be willing to change, as long as it can get finished.

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there anyway to do this?"*

```
FormName.Hide()
```

*"I hope there's also a way to undo as well?"*

```
FormName.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to hide it momentarily from prying eyes, I suggest minimising the form.

Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized